# using the (.) operand to declare methods in other classes

Tags: java

I am trying to print out the area of a rectangle using the following code

```
  System.out.println("Area of rectOne: " + rectOne.getArea());
```

however since the method getArea is defined in another class shouldn't it be

```
  System.out.println("Area of rectOne: " + rectOne.NameOfClass.getArea());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes `rectOne` is reference to instance of the class which has `getArea()` method.

`getArea()` is instance method, so, you need reference to instance of this class to access `getArea()` method.

```
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(); //Here you are getting reference to Rectangle instance.
rectOne.getArea();
```

Answer (score 2):

`rectOne` has the information of which class it is, therefore `rectOne.getArea()` has enough information to find the method.

Only `static` methods acan and should be accessed via the class name.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a declaration

```
Object rectOne = new Rectangle();
```

then you'd need

```
System.out.println("Area of rectOne: "
                   + ((Rectangle)rectOne).getArea());
```

Notice the syntax; it's different from your proposal. But, since you probably have

```
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle();
```

the compiler already knows what class you are involving when calling a method on `rectOne` so the compiler mercifully allows you to call the method without further ado.